# Как добавить несколько элементов в NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Есть `NaviagtionDrawer`, в котором содержится `RecyclerView`, и нужно чтобы при нажатии на один из пунктов выезжал справа еще один  `RecyclerView` с другими элементами списка и сдвигал влево первый `RecyclerView`, получается как двойной  `NaviagtionDrawer`. Я пробую  делать так: добавляю один `RecyclerView` c `layout_gravity="start"`  и еще один с `layout_gravity="end"`  и при нажатии на один из пунктов первого списка вызываю:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
```

Проблема в том, что он выезжает, но находиться под первым списком и не смещает его, а просто выезжает под первым, т.е. это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Меня интересует, есть ли еще какие-то способы это реализовать? Или каким образом можно вставить два `RecyclerView` с одним и тем же `layout_gravity="start"`, чтобы потом попробовать анимировать их смещение?

Вот код разметки, вместо второго `RecyclerView` я сейчас показываю просто `View` для простоты:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
            android:layout_above="@+id/appBar_layout"
            >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorTabs"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/switch_green"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

примерно то что я хочу получить более подходящей картинки я не нашел, только тут вторая менюшка маленькая и слева а мне нужно что бы выезжала такого же размера как и первая и выезжать должна справа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите скриншот, например, в каком приложении работает так, как вы хотите. Я в общих чертах понял вопрос, но хотел бы понять полностью.

Comment: я добавил картинку с описанием, т.е. пока что единственный вариант - в лоб, два RecyclerView  и анимация смещения на втором.

Comment: а как насчет показывать PopupMenu, например, по клику на пункт списка?

Comment: а как это выглядит?

Comment: что именно? Как выглядит PopupMenu? Или как его показать?

Comment: в смысле как оно будет выглядеть, просто  поверх первого списка, не выезжая сбоку?

Comment: PopupMenu можно настроить место появления, например сбоку

Comment: я понял, это выпадающий элемент, мне нужен сдвиг.

Comment: ну, на картирке, что вы привели как раз очень похоже на аналог PopupMenu, только на HTML

Comment: Да, я знаю, я к сожалению не могу найти более подходящую картинку.